# Keep first user response waiting until second user make the same request

Tags: php, laravel

I want to keep a user response waiting until the second user make the same request which the below code does..

So i want to know if theres better approach to achieve this....I'm keeping the request waiting for a short period of time which i have not implemented yet...

And i also want the response of the first user and the second user to be same after the second user has made the request..

Will value all suggestion thanks..
Note: The code below is a prototype of what i want to do

```
function laravelStream(Request $request){
        $this->game = Game::create([
            "room_id" => 6,
            "draw" => 0,
            "is_active" => 1,
            "winner_id" => 1
        ]);
        do
        {
            $this->game = Game::all();
            if($this->game->count() == 2){
                break;
            }
            
        }
        while($this->game->count() != 2);
        return $this->game;

    }
```

Comment: Maybe you'll need to use websockets to achieve this. When the game count is 2, trigger an event and listen to it where you need it and execute the needed code then.

Comment: yea...the mobile flutter guy is finding it difficult to establish connection to laravel websockets..thats why we are looking into this approach

Answer (score 1):

Use `sleep(1)` to create a pause in your script and loop until the condition is met.

```
function laravelStream(Request $request){
    $this->game = Game::create([
        "room_id" => 6,
        "draw" => 0,
        "is_active" => 1,
        "winner_id" => 1
    ]);
    do {
        sleep(1);
        $games = Game::where('room_id', 6);
    } while($games->count() < 2);
    return $this->game;
}
```

This sleep method might be preferable as it stops the script from hammering your DB with a query again and again. You might want to consider a timeout too perhaps.

Comment: I'm unsure what exactly constitutes a 'match' though.

Comment: two users can only join a match, if player 1 comes and he want to play a game, i check if theres any active match that has one active user, if theres, the user join the match and if theres not, we start a new match for that user while that user wait for another user to be matched to the same game he started

Comment: yea...i will implement timeout from the frontend and backend too..
i will try to sleep it..thanks

Comment: Thanks. Please upvote my answer if it’s been helpful to you.